# If a project under source control is copied to a different folder, is the source control retained?

Tags: iphone, xcode, svn

I have set up my project to use SVN with Xcode for version control. Now if I copy my project and paste it in a different directory, will the new project also be under source control by default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will technically be another "working copy" of your project. If you open your project directory in Terminal, you will be able to see the hidden .svn directory with `ls -al`. When you copy the project folder, those hidden .svn directories will be copied as well. If you want to a copy of your project without all of the svn files, you'll want to perform an svn [export](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re10.html).

Answer (score 1):

I should work, but beware; once you start constructing ad-hoc hierarchies with
chunks from different source areas, you can become very confused.

Answer (score 0):

As long as all of the `.svn` directories full of SVN's data are copied as well, it *SHOULD* work, though I've never tried it and don't currently have any SVN based projects laying around to try it with.